# How many objects are created

Tags: java, string, object, bytecode, stringbuilder

I was having a discussion about usage of `String`s and `StringBuffer`s in Java. How many objects are created in each of these two examples?

Ex 1:

```
String s = "a";
s = s + "b";
s = s + "c";
```

Ex 2:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("a");
sb.append("b");
sb.append("c");
```

In my opinion, Ex 1 will create 5 and Ex 2 will create 4 objects.

Comment: The first example will create 1 object as the compiler can optimise it.

Comment: Example 1 generates this: `String s = "a";
        s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("b").toString();
        s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("c").toString();
        System.err.println(s);`. It looks like javac is not optimizing that (at least in Java 6)

Comment: It should do it if it was: "a" + "b" + "c".  I'm surprised the other case isn't optimised too. But oh well ...  See: http://nicklothian.com/blog/2005/06/09/on-java-string-concatenation/

Comment: First example, Optimized? I thought all strings are unique and immutable so shouldn't it be 5 objects regardless of optimization?

Comment: @Thihara: not if the Javac (rather than JIT) compiler gets in there first.

Comment: Makes sense I guess... Thanks i didn't knew that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can determine the answer by analyzing the java bytecode (use `javap -c`). Example 1 creates two `StringBuilder` objects (see line #4) and two `String` objects (see line #7), while example 2 creates one `StringBuilder` object (see line #2).

Note that you must also take the `char[]` objects into account (since arrays are objects in Java). `String` and `StringBuilder` objects are both implemented using an underlying `char[]`. Thus, example 1 creates **eight** objects and example 2 creates **two** objects.

Example 1:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   ldc             #2; //String a
   2:   astore_1
   3:   new             #3; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   6:   dup
   7:   invokespecial   #4; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   10:  aload_1
   11:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   14:  ldc             #6; //String b
   16:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   19:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   22:  astore_1
   23:  new             #3; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   26:  dup
   27:  invokespecial   #4; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   30:  aload_1
   31:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   34:  ldc             #8; //String c
   36:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   39:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   42:  astore_1
   43:  return   
}
```

Example 2:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   new             #2; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   3:   dup
   4:   ldc             #3; //String a
   6:   invokespecial   #4; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   9:   astore_1
   10:  aload_1
   11:  ldc             #5; //String b
   13:  invokevirtual   #6; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   16:  pop
   17:  aload_1
   18:  ldc             #7; //String c
   20:  invokevirtual   #6; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   23:  pop
   24:  return  
}
```

Comment: I have a little doubt. , oracle docs here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html  says this about append: 
"public StringBuilder append(Object obj)
Appends the string representation of the Object argument.
The overall effect is exactly as if the argument were converted to a string by the method String.valueOf(Object), and the characters of that string were then appended to this character sequence."
Doesn't that mean objects will be created for String literals.

Answer (score 6):

I've used a memory profiler to get the exact counts.

On my machine, the first example creates 8 objects:

```
String s = "a";
s = s + "b";
s = s + "c";
```

- two objects of type `String`;
- two objects of type `StringBuilder`;
- four objects of type `char[]`.

On the other hand, the second example:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("a");
sb.append("b");
sb.append("c");
```

creates 2 objects:

- one object of type `StringBuilder`;
- one object of type `char[]`.

This is using JDK 1.6u30.

P.S. To the make the comparison fair, you probably ought to call `sb.toString()` at the end of the second example.

Comment: is this machine/compiler-dependent?

Comment: @AlexLockwood: Probably JDK-dependent to some extent, although I'd be quite surprised if there was much variability across recent JDKs.

Comment: It seems rather silly to distinguish between a `char[]` and it's `String` abstraction in a high-level language like Java :P. But I agree it is correct to do so (not silly on your part... just silly in a kind of stupid example like this one).

Comment: @AlexLockwood: I actually think it's very important to account for sub-objects (such as the `char[]`s in this example). Without this, the counts are largely meaningless: one can always wrap an arbitrary amount of complexity into a single object, and claim there's only one (top-level) `new`.

Comment: @aix can we really consider new char[] as a new Object since it has no corresponding class? I don't say that it does not use memory.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: Of course `char[]` is an object. All Java arrays are. If you don't believe me, try `new char[0].getClass()`, or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009210/in-java-why-are-arrays-objects-are-there-any-specific-reasons

Comment: I think both of your answers are correct. aix is correct in that you need to multiply the total number of objects by 2, since `char[]` is in fact an object. On the other hand, it does seem somewhat unnecessary to make this distinction *in the context of the original question*, since it's pretty obvious that both `String` and `StringBuilder` are implemented with an underlying `char[]`. Nonetheless, the OP asked for the "number of objects created" so I totally agree with your answer.

Comment: @aix what memory profiler are you using?  After an initial stab at an answer, I'm starting to think these questions are very sensitive to interpretation of scope.  While most will responders point to byte code and call it good, I can only imagine that the (JIT)JVM optimize this stuff away.  Aren't concepts like constant folding some of the lowest hanging fruit of compiler theory?

Comment: @ltiong_sh: For this answer, I have used YourKit. I think that looking at the top-level bytecode is not enough because any method/constructor call could potentially involve an arbitrary number of memory allocations.

Comment: @aix Thanks, I agree.  Just to add some flavor to the topic, I just wanted to attach a link to paper w/ some interesting nuggets on what happens when the JVM takes the Bytecode to IR (http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Research/Papers/Haeubl08Master/Haeubl08Master.pdf).  Interesting read.

Answer (score 5):

In terms of objects created:

Example 1 creates 8 objects:

```
String s = "a"; // No object created
s = s + "b"; // 1 StringBuilder/StringBuffer + 1 String + 2 char[] (1 for SB and 1 for String)
s = s + "c"; // 1 StringBuilder/StringBuffer + 1 String + 2 char[] (1 for SB and 1 for String)
```

Example 2 creates 2 object:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("a"); // 1 StringBuffer + 1 char[] (in SB)
sb.append("b"); // 0
sb.append("c"); // 0
```

To be fair, I did not know that new char[] actually created an Object in Java (but I knew they were created). Thanks to aix for pointing that out.

Comment: He/she could have run the test procedure in another JDK version and obtained different results.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is tied to specific implementations of the language (compiler and runtime  libraries).  Even to the presence of specific optimization options or not.  And, of course, version of the implementation (and, implicitly, the JLS it is compliant with).  So, it's better to speak in term of minima and maxima.  In fact, this exercise gives a better

For Ex1, the minimum number of objects is 1 (the compiler realizes that there are only constants involved and produces only code for `String s= "abc" ;` ).  The maximum could be just anything, depending on implementation, but a reasonable estimation is 8 (also given in another answer as the number produced by certain configuration).

For Ex2, the minimum number of objects is 2.  The compiler has no way of knowing if we have replaced StringBuilder with a custom version with different semantics, so it will not optimize.  The maximum could be around 6, for an extremely memory-conserving StringBuilder implementation that expands a backing `char[]` array one character at a time, but in most cases it will be 2 too.

Comment: The compiler 'produces code for `String s = "abc";`', but this does not create an object when executed, so the minum is actually zero.