# How many objects will be created and how many objects will be available for garbage collection?

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection

```
String str = "test";

str = str + "test2";
str = str + "test3";
str = str + "test4";
str = str + "test5";
```

How many objects will be created from the above code and how many objects will be available for garbage collection?

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443492/how-many-objects-are-created, but that question is a few years old and may be obsolete.

Comment: Looking at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1, it appears that there is no definitive answer--different implementations could do different things.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaC is very odd regarding String manipulation. For example, why dont they use String.concat when you do "String += otherString"?

Instead, Java creates a StringBuilder (or StringBuffer, depending on the Java version) for each line ended with ; that you have concatenating Strings.

I placed your code in a test program (TCTestWin) and called from command line:

```
javap -c TCTestWin.class
```

These are the results:

```
   0: ldc           #15                 // String test
   2: astore_1
   3: new           #17                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
   6: dup
   7: aload_1
   8: invokestatic  #19                 // Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
  11: invokespecial #25                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  14: ldc           #28                 // String test2
  16: invokevirtual #30                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  19: invokevirtual #34                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
  22: astore_1
  23: new           #17                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
  26: dup
  27: aload_1
  28: invokestatic  #19                 // Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
  31: invokespecial #25                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  34: ldc           #38                 // String test3
  36: invokevirtual #30                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  39: invokevirtual #34                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
  42: astore_1
  43: new           #17                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
  46: dup
  47: aload_1
  48: invokestatic  #19                 // Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
  51: invokespecial #25                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  54: ldc           #40                 // String test4
  56: invokevirtual #30                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  59: invokevirtual #34                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
  62: astore_1
  63: new           #17                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
  66: dup
  67: aload_1
  68: invokestatic  #19                 // Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
  71: invokespecial #25                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  74: ldc           #42                 // String test5
  76: invokevirtual #30                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  79: invokevirtual #34                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
  82: astore_1
  83: return
```

As you can see, for each line, JavaC creates a StringBuilder, appends the String, and continues.

Such code, specially when used inside a loop, will rush the Garbage Collector.

There are three better ways to do it:

1. Use concat instead:

   ```
   String str = "test";
   str = str.concat("test2");
   str = str.concat("test3");
   str = str.concat("test4");
   str = str.concat("test5");
   ```
2. Use a single line of concatenation, which will create a single StringBuilder. Remember that each ; will create another StringBuilder. Note that in the  concatenation of constant Strings below, the Java compiler will create a single String. However, if you add one or more String variables, then the StringBuilder will be created.

   ```
   String str = "test" + "test2" + "test3" + "test4" + "test5";
   ```
3. Create a StringBuilder yourself, do the concatenation, and **REUSE** the StringBuilder. This has the best performance, specially when doing things **in a loop**.

   ```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(512);
   for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
   {
      sb.setLength(0);
      sb.append("test");
      sb.append("test2");
      sb.append("test3");
      sb.append("test4");
      sb.append("test5");
      sb.append(i);
      String s = sb.toString();
   }
   ```

So, from the code above, 4 different StringBuilders will be created. After the final String, all StringBuilders will be collected.

Comment: If you use numbering or bullet points, following code needs to be double-indented.

Comment: They don't use multiple `String.concat()` calls because a single `StringBuilder` is considerably more efficient. There is nothing 'very odd' about a compiler choosing better object code than programmers can think of. That's what they're for. NB You haven't actually answered the question.

Comment: Completely agreed if... there a single StringBuilder was created. However, the code that was posted does NOT create a single StringBuilder, but 4!

Comment: If `String str = "test" + "test2" + "test3" + "test4" + "test5"` creates a single `StringBuilder`, I'm throwing out the compiler and getting a different one.  This should not create any `StringBuilder`.  Java has rules that say that the right-hand side is a constant expression (which makes a difference in some cases, since there are places where only constant expressions are allowed).  Because of that, the compiler should already know that it has to process this as a constant, and as a result, it should create _one_ string, `"testtest2test3test4test5"`.

Comment: @ajb, you're right. Adding String constants will make java create a single String at compile time. However, in real world, i believe he will not be adding constants, but different variables. The codes i sent will teach him what can happen in real code when adding , not this one that he sent.

Answer (score 0):

> How many objects will be created

At runtime, 4, i.e. the four computed values of `str`, excluding the initial value which comes from the constant pool.

> and how many objects will be available for garbage collection?

At the end of this code but before `str` goes out of scope, three, i.e. the three intermediate values of `str`.

Note that I am counting `Strings`. Each `String` will have an associated `char[]` which is another object.

However if the surrounding code is such that the JVM can determine that `str` cannot change between these lines of code it could be as low as one and zero respectively.

Comment: I think `String str = "test";` will also create an object in String Constant pool, that is located inside Heap memory of JVM. So the no. of objects will be 5.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad But not at runtime when this code is executed. It happens at class-loading time.