# What are the limits of std::tm or std::gmtime?

Tags: c++

`std::gmtime` is failing for me when I pass it the max possible `std::time_t`. See the following test:

```
std::cout   << "sizeof(std::time_t): " << sizeof(std::time_t) << '\n'
            << "sizeof(long long): " << sizeof(long long) << '\n'
            << "sizeof(unsigned int): " << sizeof(unsigned int) << "\n\n";

auto testgmtime = [](std::time_t time)
{
    std::tm* ptm = std::gmtime(&time);
    std::cout << (ptm ? "succeeded\n" : "failed\n");
};

testgmtime(std::numeric_limits<std::time_t>::max());
testgmtime(std::numeric_limits<long long>::max());
testgmtime(std::numeric_limits<long long>::max()-1);
testgmtime(static_cast<std::time_t>(std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max())*2);
testgmtime(std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
```

**Output:**

```
sizeof(std::time_t): 8
sizeof(long long): 8
sizeof(unsigned int): 4

failed
failed
failed
succeeded
succeeded
```

I'm using VS2012. Is there a standard limit I'm not seeing or is this VS being crappy? What alternative can I use that *works*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS2012 is not being crappy. Do the math.

If `time_t` is a 64-bit integer, then the maximum number of seconds in it is 2<sup>64</sup>-1 if it's an unsigned integer or 2<sup>63</sup>-1 if it's a signed integer.

Roughly, 2<sup>63</sup> seconds corresponds to 2<sup>63</sup>/(60*60*24*365) ≈ 2.9*10<sup>11</sup> years.

`time_t`'s `tm_year` is a 32-bit `int`, whose maximum value is 2<sup>31</sup>-1 ≈ 2.1*10<sup>9</sup>.

Clearly, you can't store ~2.9*10<sup>11</sup> in a 32-bit signed integer. And `gmtime()` rightfully fails when you ask it to.

You may be able to modify my implementation of `gmtime()` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197532/968261) to handle very large values. You'll need to workaround the overflow in `SecondsSinceEpoch + 11644473600ULL` and change some `ints` and `uints` to `uint64s`.

Comment: Thanks, that does explain the very high numbers. But `(std::numeric_limits<long long>::max()-1)/10000000` fails too, which would only be a range of ~29247years, so does a range of 2924 years, and finally a range of 292 works. I don't know where it stops exactly but this thing fails at between ~300 and ~3000 years. I guess I'll have to write my own like you suggest

Comment: You can do a binary search to determine the cut-off date/time. I'm curious to know what it is. It might reveal the logic.

Comment: ~300 to ~3000 years will take 33 to 37 bits. I wonder if the implementation is basically 32-bit despite `time_t` being 64-bit (note that you can choose `time_t` size).

Comment: The limit is 31 Dec 3000, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z9czt0w(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

C++ only says that `gmtime` may fail. The standard that specifies the behavior of `gmtime` on large input is [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gmtime.html):

> If an error is detected, gmtime() shall return a null pointer and set errno to indicate the error.
>
> ERRORS
>
> The gmtime() and gmtime_r() functions shall fail if:
>
> [EOVERFLOW]
>    The result cannot be represented.

It doesn't directly say what the limit is, although it does say that if the seconds since the Epoch are negative, their relationship to the actual time is [undefined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_15).

As an alternative, try boost

```
auto testgmtime = [](std::time_t time)
{
    std::cout << boost::posix_time::from_time_t(time) << '\n';
};
```

(although on my linux setup, from_time_t() appears to hit the ceiling earlier than gmtime)