# MilliSec To Date C++

Tags: java, c++, date, java-native-interface

I have a java program which makes a JNI call. From java, I am sending Date.getTime() (basically seconds * 1000), and I expect C++ to convert it to a perfect date.

NOT DUPLICATE: I KNOW MANY SOLUTIONS EXIST ON STACKOVERFLOW, BUT NONE OF THEM SEEM TO WORK WITH DATES SINCE 01-01-0001

I need the dates to get perfectly generated, for as early as 01-01-0001 00:00:00.

Any clue or code snippet in C++?

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that getTime() works according to the java docs outputting time since 1970.
Try this:
[How can I convert seconds since the epoch to hours/minutes/seconds in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188621/how-can-i-convert-seconds-since-the-epoch-to-hours-minutes-seconds-in-java/11197532#11197532)

(Edit: even though the question is for Java the implementation given in the first answer is in C, which is (mostly) valid C++ code. It doesn't account for leap seconds so just subtract the number of leap seconds since 1970 before evaluating)