# How do you obtain a class definition byte[] for array classes?

Tags: java, classloader

I'm trying to understand how the Java class loader works, specifically the `defineClass(String,byte[],int,int)` method.  Let's say I want to load the class definition for `NonIntrinsicType`.  I know I can find the *.class file for `NonIntrinsicType`, serialize its contents into a `byte[]` called `bytes`, and then call `defineClass(null,bytes,0,bytes.length)`.

The weird situation I'm having trouble understanding is, how can I get a `byte[]` for the class definition of something like `[LNonIntrinsicType` - in other words, if my application requests the class definition for an instance of `NonIntrinsicType[]`, I don't have a *.class file that corresponds to this class type.  How would I obtain a `byte[]` for this type's definition?

You're probably wondering why I want to do this.  I'm basically trying to create a network class loader, with a "Local" JVM that has class definitions on its class path, and a "Remote" JVM that does not have the aforementioned class definitions on its class path.  "Remote" is encountering an instance of `NonIntrinsicType[]` and requests a definition from "Local" for that class type, but my "Local" JVM can't find a class file for `NonIntrinsicType[]`, so it fails to provde a class definition `byte[]` to "Remote".

**Added 9/7/2010**

One thing I should have mentioned...  I am using `Socket` and `ObjectInputStream` to receive messages sent to "Remote" by "Local".  I've created a custom extension of `ObjectInputStream` on the "Remote" side and overrode `protected Class<?> resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass)`.  This is the first notification my "Remote" JVM gets when an incoming message contains instances of classes that have yet to be loaded.  I have another socket that I use to pass class definitions around with, so when the first socket receives an instance of a class that hasn't been loaded, it requests a definition for that class from the "Local" JVM via the second socket.

The problem happens when my custom `ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass)` gets passed an `ObjectStreamClass` that returns a class name for an array type (the name looks like `[Lsome.ClassName;`).  I can easily parse out the base-level type `some.ClassName` and load it first - this is done in the call to `NetworkClassLoader.getInstance.loadClass()`, where I get a `byte[]` for the base-level class and then use it to call `defineClass()` inside that method call.

I understand now that you probably can't get a `byte[]` for an array type's class definition, so that leaves me trying to figure out how to find the `Class<?>` instance for the array type and return it.  Here's the code for my `resolveClass` method in my custom `ObjectInputStream` on the "Remote" JVM's message-receiving `Socket`:

```
@Override
protected Class<?> resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass osc) 
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    try {
        return super.resolveClass(osc);
    } catch (Exception e){}

    String name = osc.getName();
    boolean array = name.contains("[L");

    if(array) name = name.replace("[L","").
            replace("[","").replace(";","");

    Class<?> c = NetworkClassLoader.getInstance().loadClass(name);
    if(!array) return c;

    //If it's an array type, how do I obtain its corresponding
    //Class<?> and return it here?

    throw new ClassNotFoundException();
}
```

Comment: Arrays probably don't have byte code that defines them. If your remote JVM has the byte code for the element type, cannot it figure it out from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need to create a definition for `[LType`. If you have a `Class`, you can create an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int...%29) of that class with reflection:

```
Object array = Array.newInstance(yourClass, dimensions);
```

Comment: Oh sure - I understand that I don't need to explicitly create a class definition for array types, but such a definition must exist somewhere - presumably memory-resident... right?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009210/in-java-why-are-arrays-objects-are-there-any-specific-reasons

Comment: Duh... I get it now.  This worked perfectly.  My classloader basically calls the method you mentioned and returns `array.getClass()`.  No more problems :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't control the loading of arrays, because they aren't loaded. There's nothing to load. There's no class for an array. There's no class definition. There's no byte[].

Comment: A classloader will not be asked to load `[LSomething` (just Something). (My assumption, someone please confirm)

Comment: That's what I was trying to express.

Comment: I see.  So even though the first class name seen by the "Remote" JVM is `[LNonIntrinsicType`, I should just have the "Local" JVM provide the definition for `NonIntrinsicType` to "Remote", then have "Remote" attempt to load `[LNonIntrinsicType` again?

Answer (score 0):

The only way this can be done is to patch your JVM's defineClass(...) method to look for the class(es) you want and then store them for later use.

Answer (score 0):

Array classes are created by JVM without calling `defineClass()`.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3.3

Answer (score 0):

This excerpt from the [ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) javadoc:

> Class objects for array classes are not created by class loaders, but
>   are created automatically as required by the Java runtime. The class
>   loader for an array class, as returned by Class.getClassLoader() is
>   the same as the class loader for its element type; if the element type
>   is a primitive type, then the array class has no class loader.

It would be interesting to understand how your classloader gets asked to create a class for `[LNonIntrinsicType`. It feels like you're doing something custom. If you could describe in more detail what you're doing, we could better understand your problem. What is the call stack when your class loader is asked to define `[LNonIntrinsicType`?